# Simplify integral to determine optimal solar panel tilt angle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

After noticing the popularity of questions about integrals on this forum, I wanted to share the problem of shedding some light on the following integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}dt\,\left(\sin(\nu(t))\cos(\theta-\alpha)\cos(\delta(t))+\nu(t)\sin(\theta-\alpha)\sin(\delta(t))\right)$$
wherein
$$\nu(t)=\cos^{-1}\left(-\tan(\theta)\tan(\delta(t))\right),\qquad \delta(t)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sin(\delta_0)\sin(t)\right).$$

The question would be to reduce the integral to an as transparent as possible expression, if you will after tuning the parameter $\alpha$ to the value where it maximizes the integral. Relatedly, a simple expression for the optimal value of $\alpha$ would be nice.

In this question, there are of course the variable parameters $\theta$ and $\delta_0$ and I'll give a bit of explanation of what they and the other (derived) quantities might represent:

1. $t$ represents a time-coordinate in units so that one earth-year has length $2\pi$, $\theta$ represents the latitude on the globe, $\alpha$ the angle by which the solar panels are removed away from the (local) zenith, toward the south. (The implicit assumption here is that we do not change the panel's tilt throughout the year)
2. $\nu(t)$ is the seasonal [angle of sunrise/sunset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation).
3. $\delta(t)$ is the seasonal [sun declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination), i.e. the time-dependent angle that the earth's rotational axis makes compared to the normal of the earth-sun orbital plane. The maximal declination $\delta_0$ would be $23.45^\circ$

Comment: Everything that isn't a function of $t$ here is just a complicated way of expressing a constant. Replace those constants with simple letters will go a long way in clarifying the integral. Beyond that, $\cos^{-1}$ and $\sin^{-1}$ are not single-valued, and which values you choose for their output will change the values you get from your integral, so you need carefully examine which velues make sense for the definitions you give for the quantities they calculation. The "principle" ranges of $[0,\pi]$ and $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ may not always be the appropriate choice.

Comment: As for the optimization, just differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ and set the result to $0$. You get$$\tan(\theta - \alpha) = \dfrac{\int_0^{2\pi}dt\,\nu(t)\sin(\delta(t))}{\int_0^{2\pi}dt\,\sin(\nu(t))\cos(\delta(t))}$$ (I have to ask, is that naked $\nu(t)$ correct? all your other $\nu, \delta$ functions are inside trig functions.)

Comment: The naked $\nu$ is correct yes. As for the inverse trig functions, I'm making the standard choices (the ones which you cited). I'll consider your recommendation to rework my question a little bit, but I doubt now whether it will gain much traction regardless.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}dt\,\left(\sin(\nu(t))\cos(\theta-\alpha)\cos(\delta(t))+\nu(t)\sin(\theta-\alpha)\sin(\delta(t))\right)
\\= \cos(\theta-\alpha)\int_0^{2\pi}\sin \nu(t)\cos \delta(t)\,dt+ \sin(\theta-\alpha)\int_0^{2\pi}\nu(t)\sin \delta(t)\,dt$$

So what you really need to calculate is the two integrals
$$\begin{align}A &= \int_0^{2\pi}\sin \nu(t)\cos \delta(t)\,dt\\B &= \int_0^{2\pi}\nu(t)\sin \delta(t)\,dt\end{align}$$
And as I noted in a comment, the optimal value of $\alpha$ is found by $$\tan(\theta - \alpha) = \frac BA$$
This equation will give two solutions in $[0,2\pi]$. One will be a maximum, and the other a minimum. When you get an actual value, it should be pretty obvious which is which.

To simplify, let $m = \sin\delta_0, n = \tan\theta$. Then we get
$$\begin{align}
\delta(t) &= \sin^{-1}(m\sin t)\\
\sin \delta(t) &= m\sin t\\
\cos\delta(t) &= \sqrt{1 - m^2\sin^2 t}\\
\tan \delta(t) &= \frac{m\sin t}{\sqrt{1 - m^2\sin^2 t}}\\
\nu(t) &= \cos^{-1}\frac{-nm\sin t}{\sqrt{1 - m^2\sin^2 t}} \\
\sin \nu(t) &= \sqrt{1-\frac{n^2m^2\sin^2 t}{1 - m^2\sin^2 t}}= \sqrt{\frac{1 - (1+n^2)m^2\sin^2 t}{1 - m^2\sin^2 t}}\end{align}$$
And the two integrals become
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1 - (1+n^2)m^2\sin^2 t}\,dt\\
B = \int_0^{2\pi}m\sin t\cos^{-1}\frac{-nm\sin t}{\sqrt{1 - m^2\sin^2 t}}\,dt
$$
which is all I have time for right now.